# How do I determine the Direct3D WARP supported feature level?

Tags: direct3d, direct3d11, warp

[Windows Advanced Rasterization Platform (WARP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg615082.aspx) supports a [variety of feature levels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg615082.aspx#capabilities) that vary based on the version of the DirectX API that is installed:

- feature levels 9_1, 9_2, 9_3, 10_0, and 10_1 when Direct3D 11 is installed
- all above feature levels plus 11_0 when Direct3D 11.1 is installed on Windows 7
- all above feature levels plus 11_1 when Direct3D 11.1 is installed on Windows 8

How can I easily determine what feature level is available via WARP? I know for the hardware device I can run [`ID3D11Device::GetFeatureLevel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476528.aspx), but I don't see an equivalent for WARP.

Comment: You should be able to call `GetFeatureLevel` when using WARP as well.  Are you seeing problems with that?

Comment: @MooseBoys, the documentation says that `GetFeatureLevel` returns *"a member of the D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL enumerated type that describes the feature level of the **hardware** device."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the code from [Anatomy of Direct3D 11 Create Device](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/02/05/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device.aspx) but use the WARP device type instead.

```
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL lvl[] = {
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0 };

DWORD createDeviceFlags = 0;
#ifdef _DEBUG
createDeviceFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif

ID3D11Device* pDevice = nullptr;
ID3D11DeviceContext* pContext = nullptr;
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL fl;
HRESULT hr = D3D11CreateDevice( nullptr, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP, nullptr,
    createDeviceFlags, lvl, _countof(lvl),
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &pDevice, &fl, &pContext );
if ( hr == E_INVALIDARG )
{
    hr = D3D11CreateDevice( nullptr, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP, nullptr,
       createDeviceFlags, &lvl[1], _countof(lvl)-1,
       D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &pDevice, &fl, &pContext );
}
if ( FAILED(hr) )
    // error handling
```

Then check `fl` to see if it is 10.1, 11.0, or 11.1. We don't need to list the 9.1, 9.2, or 9.3 feature level in `lvl` since WARP supports at least 10.1 on Windows desktop PCs. For robustness, I'd suggest listing 10.0 as well.